# Extracurricular activities in cover letter

Tags: application-cover-letter, workshop

I am a science PhD student applying for a workshop on documentaries and video art forms, organised for liberal arts students. In the past few years I worked part time as a reporter; in your opinion, what is the best way to describe my background?

What I have now is

> I am a PhD student in bla bla with [a passion for]/[experience in] journalism and multimedia storytelling

But I am not very happy of any of the solutions. Let me know if you have any tips on how to improve the phrase!

Comment: My feeling is that both alternatives are fine and that it doesn't really matter (since the chances that carefully phrasing this sentence will change the outcome of your application are very slim).  I'd bet you're really overthinking this.  Is there a reason you are particularly concerned about this sentence?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, you're probably right about the overthinking part ;-) Maybe it's because I'm not a native English speaker, but to me both alternatives suggested an idea of something amateurish... I was wandering if there was a way to express my abilities without giving that impression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your extracurricular activities are certainly relevant here, so you can just say what they have been.  You've done so quite clearly here:

> In the past few years I worked part time as a reporter.

Now just add a sentence that notes how this connects to your interest in the workshop, and you should be fine.